# Replacement brake pads for Tektro HD-R210

Tags: disc-brake, brake-pads

What model pads would be a replacement for Tektro HD-R210 brakes?

I haven't seen the model mentioned in Tektro's documentation
https://www.tektro.com/upload/Product/F_20170613131999DtkdK8.PDF

The bike is a 2019 Giant Fastroad SL-1 
https://www.giant-bicycles.com/au/fastroad-sl-1-2019

Around the front calliper the only marking is F140 FM1.1

I don't see any marking on the rotor for resin only.

The front brakes have been a bit noisy & bumpy under medium braking, and the pads look thinner at the side closer to the rear of the bicycle. It looks a bit like there's wear on the outer of the rotor arms. I guess this is related to pad wear?

I'll swap the left and right pads over until I get a new set, hopefully that will put a bit more pad where it's needed.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This appears to be an OEM-oriented brake with no published data, which isn't uncommon for Tektro, but it does mean you'll need to post a pic of the pad to answer with any certainty. It's also certainly one of two different Shimano-derived pad shapes, one of which is more "flat-mounty," but Tektro/TRP have done flat mount brakes with both styles. We also need to know whether your rotor happens to be labeled resin-only.

Comment: Thanks @NathanKnutson :) I've added some pictures and details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the most common Shimano-originated pad form factor type, which doesn't have any one agreed-upon name but is often listed as "M525/515", "Deore Mechanical", "M475/425" and others. The "A10.11" is the Tektro model for the pads you have, which are what they call a metallic ceramic compound. You could just keep it simple and get more of those, but all the aftermarket pad manufacturers plus Shimano have offerings for this type in both metallic and organic/resin. There are a lot of questions here about organic vs metallic. Shimano B01S is an extremely cheap but good quality resin pad that would work.

The noise/chatter you mentioned is most often related to inadequate bedding. Metallic pads make it worse and will give some noise even when things are going right.